# Configuring redirect strategy

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, rest-assured

I'm testing an endpoint that returns a `Location` header with spaces ( it can't be fixed ) and I receive `org.apache.http.ClientProtocolException`. According to other answers, I have to create `RedirectStrategy` and encode spaces with `%20`.

Looking through the documentation I found a small section about `HTTP Client` config but it seems it contains only basic info.

How can I set `RedirectStrategy` to `RestAssured` to encode spaces in the `Location` header with `%20` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [HttpClientConfig](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#http-client-config) allows you to set a custom HttpClient instance to which you can specify the redirect strategy. Unfortunately the HttpClient instance must extend `org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient` in order to work with REST Assured. Here's an example that should work:

```
given().config(RestAssured.config().httpClient(HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig().httpClientFactory(() -> {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpClient.setRedirectStrategy(..);
        return httpClient;
    }))). ..
```

You can also configure this for all tests:

```
RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().httpClient(HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig().httpClientFactory(() -> {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpClient.setRedirectStrategy(..);
            return httpClient;
        });
```

Or in a [request specification](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#specification-re-use).